# cant get the sub-surf right (Blender guru beginner modeling tutorial)

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

So I have been following the Blender Guru modeling tutorial with minor changes every thing looked OK till he added the sub-surf modifier and I have no idea how to fix  (followed tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM )

this is my edit view with and with out sub surf
[image]

[image]

and this is how it should look like[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess your mesh has something different in the bottom: I think you have a single bottom face (N-gon), which is causing this issue...

if you have this (sorry for the horrible mesh, I'm before breakfast...)

[image]

subsurf behaves well

[image]

while if you have a single N-gon face

[image]

subsurf behaves like in your model

[image]

if unsure, share your model through

http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

then edit your question and post the provided link...

edit:
after getting your file I found that this model has (still) several issues: at the base there are still n-gons, ruining the subsurf effect, but overall it has some other modeling issues... giving aso bad mirroring results.

About the ngons, this what you have one side

[image]

and the opposite is even worse

[image]

then below you have some faces with inverted normals

[image]

then again, its quite irregular on lines that are supposed to be quite linear instead: this ruins both mirror and subsurf

eg: here

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Nothing terrible, and it can be corrected, but I suggest you to try to model keeping an eye on such things, because it helps you model better, and get better results. First, I recalculated normals (select  all in edit mode, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)

Then I tried to remove those ngons, getting something like this

[image]

if you enable subsurf now, it looks better, but not at its best:

[image]

it lacks some subdivision at the base, eg:

[image]

with this further subdivision,

[image]

the base becomes more defined when you subsurf later

[image]

Here is the file a bit corrected (imho, it could still be improved)

[image]

Hth, Marco

Comment: To add to this, use the knife tool to get rid of the N-gon by adding the needed edges.

Comment: yeah I think that is the problem i will give it a shot and come back at ya

Comment: Ok so I did that and still came out weird i have no idea what to do

Comment: As said above, share your model.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: @CatMann  I edited my answer to show you some issues and a possible way to fix...

Comment: just a little question  how do i hide the grid on the mesh ?

Comment: Look under object properties tab, uncheck "wire" and "draw all edges" (see bottom right in the last image)

Answer (score 0):

You model has faces on the bottom but his doesn't, that is your main problem. Where you have the crease about halfway up is caused by faces inside your model. Go to face select mode, and in wireframe view you can easily select and delete the extra faces.

Comment: well it looks good when i remove the bottom face  but i don't remember him removing it so i don't really know what to do now since the anvil has no bottom